# Django overriding save method to save multiple objects at once

Tags: python, django

i need some help here. I'm trying to create multiple objects at once when saving in admin panel. But the problem is, only the last value in the loop is being saved. I tried setting the primary key to None

```
class Seat(models.Model):
    seat = models.CharField(default='Seat', max_length=5, unique=True, primary_key=False)
    available = models.BooleanField()
    theater = models.ForeignKey(Theater, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def clean(self):
        if model.objects.count() >= self.theater.capacity:
            raise ValidationError(' - Maximum seats exceeded!')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        seats_name = []
        row_label = [chr(letter) for letter in range(65, 91)]
        row_track = 0
        row_range = 10

        col_range = self.theater.capacity // row_range
        col_track = 0

        for n in range(self.theater.capacity):
            row_track += 1

            if row_track > row_range:
                row_track = 1
                col_track += 1

            display = "{} | {}-{}".format(self.theater, row_label[col_track], row_track)
            seats_name.append(display)

        for seat in seats_name:
            self.seat = seat
        super(Seat, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.seat
```

Comment: Well `self.seat` is a `CharField`, so if you save it multiple times, eventually the *last* update will persist overwriting the old ones.

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking about that. So how can i save another instance of CharField in that class? So it will generate multiple sets of data.

Comment: @Clark you can not save multiple values in one row. You need to use ForeignKey relation and create another model specially for "seat" CharField, so you can create multiple objects and attach them to your main model using ForeignKey relation

Comment: As another option, if you don't need to search these objects by this field and use any filters on this field, you can increase maximum length and store data as comma-separated, colon-separated etc. values